# How to get query time from a Sunspot Search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I've implemented Sunspot to do searching on a Rails App. Is there any way to get the time the query took to execute?

Eg. 10 records returned in **0.5 seconds**

I've been searching around the sunspot docs, but i can't seem to find out if they support this or not.

Answer (score 4):

The query time is not exposed in the Sunspot public API but it is available in the returned search object. Place the following monkey match into an initializer (such as `config/initializers/sunspot_query_time.rb`):

```
class Sunspot::Search::AbstractSearch
  def query_time
    @solr_result['responseHeader']['QTime']
  end
end
```

You can then call `query_time` on any search object to get query time in milliseconds.

Comment: Jason, drop that in a pull request and I'll get it in the next release ;)